# Passing data in form of array not OBJECT using services

Tags: angular

The data is been posted in form of object,but I need to post in form of array.I have tried using  `JSON.stringify()` to post the data in form of array.Do `Http Headers` decide in which format the data is to be sent?

**Code :**

```
 Bill_to(data) {
   let url = "api/xyz"
   let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
   let body = JSON.stringify(data);
   console.log("Inside bill_to service" + data);
   return this.http.post(url,data,{headers:headers})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to send just data from the Object then you can use

```
Object.values(data)
```

Your modified code as

```
 Bill_to(data) {
   let url = "api/xyz"
   let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
   let body = Object.values(data);
   console.log("Inside bill_to service" + data);
   return this.http.post(url,data,{headers:headers})
}
```

Comment: It still shows "Inside bill_to service [object Object]" in console.I was expecting the values that was given by end user to be displayed

Comment: That is issue the argument you passed to `console.log`. You should use `console.log("Inside bill_to service", data);`. Note : I had put `,` instead of `+`

Comment: Even if its object the data I have posted should enter database right?

Comment: Thats right, you can post your `data` directly. No need to convert.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: I thought my mistake was the conversion part!

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this:

```
doSomething(id: number, userid: number, dk: Object[]) {
    let bodyString = JSON.stringify({ id: id, userid: userid, dk: dk });
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON' });
    return this._http.post<any>('invoices/dosomething', bodyString, { headers: headers });
    }
```

Comment: If I have given   <input placeholder="Phone no." type="text" name="phone"  ngModel> ,  <input placeholder="Name" type="text" name="name"  ngModel>,how should I pass this using stringify?

Comment: @ kedar kulk `doSomething(phone: string, name: string) {
 let bodyString = JSON.stringify({ phone: phone, name: name});
 let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON' });
 return this._http.post<any>('invoices/dosomething', bodyString, { headers: headers });
    }`